# Routing with react bootstrap not working when built

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-bootstrap

I have a website at

ryancodes.co.uk

where the routing in the navbar returns a 404 error on the about/skills/qualifications links.

I works fine locally not built.

It can be checked out at:

https://github.com/ryandixon555/website

with the code in question at:

https://github.com/ryandixon555/website/blob/master/src/App.jsx

Comment: Show us error in development envoriment

Comment: There isn't one in the console. It just gives a 404 not found as if the path is incorrect/not there. It also runs fine on the dev environment.